# Ereader that won't blur pdfs

Tags: ebook-readers, pdf

I have the 2015 Kindle Wi-fi Touch. It's great, although when I try to read PDFs on it, it blurs them.

I don't have a problem with small fonts, and I realise that ereaders are never going to be optimal for PDFs. But is there an ereader that, at least, will not blur PDFs?

Answer (score 2):

Quality resolution for PDFs is awfully dependent on screen size. The bigger the display, the easier it is to read.

I don't have much experience working with Kindle's PDF converter/reader, but it's possible that this pdf uses formatting which the converter cannot process.

You might find interesting my answer on this topic. [is PDF not considered as an ebook format](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/6890/is-pdf-not-considered-as-an-ebook-format)

Answer (score 2):

I have a 1<sup>st</sup> gen Kobo Glo, and it renders PDF files pretty well.

I have to say that I don't usually use my ereader with PDF files, a 6 inch screen is really not the best way to read an A4 sized page, but the text is readable and clear, albeit small sized.

I can't test this with more recent Kobo devices, but being more or less the same firmware, the experience shouldn't be very different.

---

A couple of pics, so you can judge by yourself (the actual rendering is a bit sharper, the slight "blur" is caused by the photograph, not by the device).

[image]
[image]