# Is it possible to take a screenshot from a Kobo ereader device?

Tags: ebook-readers, kobo, kobo-glo

While answering [another question](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/7156/ereader-that-wont-blur-pdfs), I had to post a couple of pictures of my Kobo Glo screen; these were taken by photographing it with my smartphone.

I was wondering if there is some way to take a screenshot from the device itself, I.E. by pressing some combination of keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible if you change the code of your Kobo a bit. A broad explanation and functions is explained in this forum post on another website: [Mobile Read Kobo](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=218376).

You must add the following code to the file `Kobo eReader.conf`, located in the `{device_root_dir}/.kobo/Kobo/` directory:

```
[FeatureSettings]
Screenshots=true
```

Then everytime you press the powerbutton, you will take a screenshot with your Kobo Glo. This image is then stored as a PNG in the root directory.

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Thank you, I edited a bit your answer to explicitly name the file that has to be edited.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the

[FeatureSettings]
Screenshots=true

thing on a Kobo Clara HD today.
The whole code has to be added, there is no [FeatureSettings] line.

- It works, screenshots are added to the root directory, whenever the power button is pushed, without any notice.
  But.
- The function of the power button is replaced, the device can not be switched off anymore, when the set time runs out, it can not be woken up from Standby.
- It can be woken up by connecting it to a PC.
- Conclusion: This is not practical.