# Can I keep a reading diary on my device?

Tags: ebook-readers, kobo

I have a Kobo Aura One. After finishing a book, I try to take some notes (something like a reading diary). Sometimes the notes become a review, sometimes I write something personal which few other people would benefit from reading.

At the moment, I write this as a review (i.e. select the option “Write a review” after the book is finished). I dislike this for two reasons:

- I can’t get as personal as I sometimes want to
- I can’t (as far as I know) store these reviews on my device

I’m aware that I could use annotations for this, but I prefer to keep that for specific passages in the book. Is there something else I can do?

Comment: Where do you store these reviews containing your reading diary.  Why do you say you write it as a review?  In what sense is it a review, rather that some text you are writing for whatever purpose?

Comment: After finishing, there’s an option to rate the book and write a review. This later appears in the store where I can purchase books. That’s what I mean with writing a review, and why I avoid making it too personal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not directly keep a diary on your device of your written reviews. If that is your question. You can indeed write your review on the device after finishing the book. And you can always find it online on the Kobo.com website.

What is maybe an option but rarely used, is to make a screenshot of your written review. This can be done by editing the code of your device a little bit. More of the explanation about that can be found in this question: [Is it possible to take a screenshot from a Kobo ereader device?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/7162/is-it-possible-to-take-a-screenshot-from-a-kobo-ereader-device/7166#7166)

If you can categorize your annotations that would also be an option to annotate your review stuff and divide it for annotations of the specific passages in the book and annotations for the review parts in the book.